# angular Jasmine - cannot set property of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My component code:

```
public save() {
  this.gridService.gridCellUpdated = false;
}
```

My Jasmine code

```
class GridServiceMock {
  public gridCellUpdated = false;
}
let gridService: GridService;
beforeEach(
  async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ModalComponent, BsModalDirective],
      providers: [{ provide: GridService, use: GridServiceMock }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
);

it('should save assets', () => {
  gridService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GridService);
  component.save();
  expect(gridService.gridCellUpdated).toBeFalsy();
});
```

My error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'gridCellUpdated' of undefined
```

Edit:
Updated the code by following below solutions but still get the same error.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I disagree with them so I'll **null** it out...

Comment: Have you tried injecting it into your test? `inject([GridService], (gridService: GridService)` ?

Comment: I think it's related to the fact that gridService is not component property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `provide` and `useClass` to provide this service here. That's generally done when you have to create a custom/lightweight implementation of a service on your own(For instance, when you have things like Angular's `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` injected as a dependency on you controller).

For the current scenario though, you just need a reference to the injected dependency for a service that you have created.

So you can simply use the `providers` array to provide it to your testing module, like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ ModalComponent ],
    providers: [ GridService ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

And then you can get a reference to the `GridService` by using `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GridService);` and test your `save` method like this:

```
describe('save', () => {

  it('should set gridCellUpdated on GridService to false', () => {

    let gridService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GridService);
    expect(gridService.gridCellUpdated).toBeTruthy();

    component.save();

    expect(gridService.gridCellUpdated).toBeFalsy();

  });

});
```

**Update**
If you still have to use the `provide` way of providing your service, use `useClass` instead of `use`. Something like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ ModalComponent ],
    providers: [ { provide: GridService, useClass: GridServiceMock } ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

And to write the test the same way as told. It should work.

**UPDATE**
Here's the whole test file, just for your reference:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { GridService } from './../../services/grid.service';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';

class GridServiceMock {
  public gridCellUpdated = false;
}

describe('ModalComponent', () => {
  let component: ModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ModalComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: GridService, useClass: GridServiceMock } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('save', () => {

    it('should set gridCellUpdated on GridService to false', () => {

      let gridService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(GridService);
      expect(gridService.gridCellUpdated).toBeTruthy();

      component.save();

      expect(gridService.gridCellUpdated).toBeFalsy();

    });

  });

});
```

And the tests are passing:

[image: Passing Tests]

Hope that helps!

Comment: followed this way too but the error remains the same.

Comment: In your question you're referring to your service via your controller(`component.gridService.gridCellUpdated`). Did you update that? You should check again. Probably something's still missing.

Comment: Please check my new code. I updated by following the solutions.

Comment: You're still using the `providers: [{ provide: GridService, use: GridServiceMock }]` to provide your service. I've specified not to do that.

Comment: Isn't there any way where I could use the mocked service? that's what I am been asked to do

Comment: You should be asking them as to why they're telling you to do it this way. I've updated my answer anyway. It should work with the latest updated answer that I provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156453/discussion-between-siddharth-ajmera-and-ish).

Answer (score 2):

as @Vega mentioned in his comment: the service is not a property of the component. It will be injected.

Your setup of the Testing Module is correct and you can get the service from the Testbed like this:

```
let gridService: GridService;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalComponent>;
let component: ModalComponent;

TestBed.configureTestingModule({...});

TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent( ModalComponent ); 
  component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  gridService= fixture.debugElement.injector.get( GridService );
} );
```

It will get an instance of the GridService as GridServiceMock. Your test should success now.

Regards

Comment: Did the same way like you said. but the I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Spent 15 mins trying to find out why this was happening only to find out I had missed to declare the it() block and directly writing my test case statements inside describe() block. Make sure your statements are inside it() block.